# Equalize a white balance, colors, contrast and brightness in multiples images

Tags: beanshell, imagej, fiji

I just discovered for myself the new word of imageJ

Found this example of histogram matching: [Histogram match between two images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25096584/2215679)

Can some one help to make a script to equalize white balance, colors, contrast and brightness from one "good picture" to bunch of other pictures.

Let see this example, I have three timelapse pictures:

Bad contrast (sun reflection)
[image: Bad contrast (sun reflection)]

Different White Balance:
[image: Bad (different) white balance]

"Good" image, I would like others to have contrast/brightness/white balance like this one:
[image: Good image, other images should looks like this one]

Comment: This question is too broad. If you need general help on how to apply batch processing with scripts in ImageJ, I recommend asking on the [image.sc forum](https://forum.image.sc) as stated in the `imagej` tag description.

Comment: Not exactly, what I'm looking is what operations apart of `matchHistograms` can I perform, to make two pictures to have similar contrast, WB etc..

Comment: @JanEglinger I just edited the question, and added the example. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Seeing the amount of replies you got here, I'd still recommend to ask on the image.sc forum: you'll most probably get a response quicker, as there are many more image processing experts around.